# Autohotkey SendRaw adding EOL

Tags: autohotkey

AutoHotkey script to paste clipboard content as plain text(using windows+v), but it inserts extra EOL characters at each new line.

My script is:

```
#v::
  SendRaw %clipboard%
Return
```

I copied content like:

```
  1: bolded line
  2: italicized line2
  3. normal line
```

And expect it to paste:

```
  1: bolded line
  2: italicized line2
  3. normal line
```

But i get:

```
  1: bolded line

  2: italicized line2

  3. normal line
```

Please Note: the issue occurs in Windows 7 and 10 with AuthoHotkey v1.1.24.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In Windows, the EOL characters are usually CRLFs, that is, two characters: CR (carriage return, Chr(13)) and LF (linefeed, Chr(10)).
- SendRaw interprets these as two enter keypresses that need to be sent to the window or control.
- The workaround is to use the following code:

-

```
#v::
vText := Clipboard
StringReplace, vText, vText, `r`n, `n, All
SendRaw %vText%
Return
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was aware that windows uses CRLF, but wasn't aware that AutoHotkey treated CRLF as 2 new lines.  I couldn't find any documentation or complaints regarding this behavior.